# Any chance of repairing a broken LUKS encrypted SD?

Tags: mount, encryption, luks

Is there any way of repairing a broken LUKS encrypted SD card? When I try to mount under Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 in Nautilus, it gives me this error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/dm-1 at /media/adrian/16GB_Luks1: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/dm-1" "/media/adrian/16GB_Luks1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/mapper/luks-5572986f-9288-4c03-973d-af8c6454ea3b is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/luks-5572986f-9288-4c03-973d-af8c6454ea3b,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I was literally just planning to backup the disk, so help would really be appreciated! :(

Comment: I tried [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/surviving-a-linux-filesystem-failures.html) but it doesn't seem to find the superblock backups at all:
`sudo mke2fs -n /dev/mmcblk0
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/mmcblk0: Read-only file system while setting up superblock`

Comment: Okay, I have no idea why, but it apparently decided to work again :S I'm going to backup the data asap.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the SD card is somehow locked to read-only. Maybe the "read-only" switch (write protect switch) is on, maybe the card reader is dirty and the "ro" switch is stuck, maybe the card itself is failing (I've read that sometimes cards & USB drives fail that way).

I have a card where the little switch broke & fell off completely. It was always read-only, and I had to put a little piece of tape over where the switch used to be, then it was read-write (rw) and still works ok.

If it happens again, double-check the card's swtich, and definitely look in the syslog &/or `dmesg | tail`

This page ([Hack: Why Is My SD Card Write Protected?](http://www.getflashmemory.info/hack-why-is-my-sd-card-write-protected/)) has more info on the write protect switch, how it works and how to "hack" it to always writeable.

[image]

And for the future, definitely keep a copy of the LUKS header, just in case there's some problem reading the drive/card in the future. At least you'll be able to decrypt whatever is left readable if the header is ever damaged. A full backup of the data on the card is an especially good idea now too, in case it is failing.